# How to make two functions void decToBin(unsigned long d) and unsigned long binToDec(char b[]) to convert numbers from decimal to binary and vice versa

Tags: c++

I have trouble with char arrays. Also the char array is 33 because unsigned long is 32 bit long and the last bit is for null. I need to use a do while loop to create a menu based number conversion

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void decToBin(unsigned long n,int size,char str[],int i=0);
unsigned long binToDec(char b[],int size,int i=0);

int main()
{
    int dec,ch,bits=sizeof(long)*8;
    char bin[bits+1];
    do
    {
        dec=0;
        memset(bin,'0',bits);
        cout<<"\n\n\t\tMENU"<<endl;
        cout<<"1.Decimal to Binary number"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.Binary to Decimal number"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter your choice(1/2/3)";
        cin>>ch;
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"Enter a Decimal Number: ";
                cin>>dec;
                decToBin(dec,bits,bin);
                cout<<dec<<" in decimal = "<<bin<<" in binary"<<endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"Enter a Binary Number: ";
                cin>>bin;
                cout<<bin<<" in binary = "<<binToDec(bin,bits)<<" in decimal"<<endl;
                break;
            case 3: break;
            default: cout<<"Invalid choice";
        }
    }while(ch!=3);
};

void decToBin(unsigned long n,int size,char str[],int i=0)
{
    if(i>size)
    {
        break;
    }
    if(n>pow(2,size-i))
    {
        str[i]='1';
        n-=pow(2,size-i);
    }
    else
        str[i]='0';
    decToBin(n,size,str,i+1);
};
unsigned long binToDec(char b[],int size,int i=0)
{
    if(i>size-1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return (unsigned long)((b[size-1-i]-'0')*pow(2,i)+binToDec(b,size,i+1));
}
```

I could not understand char array properly. I have some little issues with pointers. Please Help Me. I'm using Embarcado Dev C++. There are many errors. The errors are as follows

```
42  6   D:\c++\CS4 Number Conversion.cpp    [Error] default argument given for parameter 4 of 'void decToBin(long unsigned int, int, char*, int)' [-fpermissive]
6   6   D:\c++\CS4 Number Conversion.cpp    [Note] previous specification in 'void decToBin(long unsigned int, int, char*, int)' here
D:\c++\CS4 Number Conversion.cpp    In function 'void decToBin(long unsigned int, int, char*, int)':
46  3   D:\c++\CS4 Number Conversion.cpp    [Error] break statement not within loop or switch
D:\c++\CS4 Number Conversion.cpp    At global scope:
57  15  D:\c++\CS4 Number Conversion.cpp    [Error] default argument given for parameter 3 of 'long unsigned int binToDec(char*, int, int)' [-fpermissive]
7   15  D:\c++\CS4 Number Conversion.cpp    [Note] previous specification in 'long unsigned int binToDec(char*, int, int)' here
```

Comment: What is the expected input and output of your program? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show a [mre]

Comment: I need to make a menu based program with do while loop. These functions are crucial. Also assigning `sizeof(long)*8+1` zeroes in the code is tough. I'm working on a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have made my minimal reprouducible example. But its not working Properly. It causes an error. I didn't understand pointer and array concepts fully. Please Help

Comment: please add the error to your question

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've included the errors and also tried to minimize the error.

Comment: you can only put default parameters in one place not in both the declaration and definition of the function (usually best in the declaration). The other error is fairly self explanatory? You have a `break` in `decToBin` but no loop to break out of

Comment: Thank You. It was so helpful